# Error in Rack::Request aftet use FormData function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, rake, form-data

I have webapp on Rails 3.2.13. If I make ajax request:

```
    $.ajax( {
    url: '/my_action',
    type: 'POST',
    data: new FormData( $('#my-form-id') ),
    cache: false,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false
    } ); return false;
```

I have the follow error:

```
    TypeError - no implicit conversion of nil into Hash:
    rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/request.rb:221:in `params'
    rack-openid (1.3.1) lib/rack/openid.rb:94:in `call'
```

The reason for this is in sent jQuery object into FormData instead of HTML-element. It sent null POST-params and Rack::Request can't process it.

My questions: is it bug, vulnerability or feature of RoR? Is any alternative of FormData in jQuery?

Comment: Most probably you're sending malformed params. `FormData` it's not necessarily the culprit here, the form itself may not be vaild. Have you tried to submit it manually?

Comment: Manually submit works fine. On form I have only one field for file.

Comment: Ahh, a file field! The thing is that there is no trivial/universal way to send multipart forms via ajax. Please have a look at https://github.com/JangoSteve/remotipart which tries to workaround the problem. And you can read about the problem in more detail here: http://www.ajaxf1.com/tutorial/ajax-file-upload-tutorial.html

Comment: No matter which field type I set. It failed with text field too. For such request `self.POST == nil` into params-function in Rack::Request. If I write data: `new FormData( $('#my-form-id')[0] )` all work fine, especially with file field.

Comment: Hmm, that's interesting. Will get back to you if I come up with anything, regarding your issue.

Comment: That's most likely because $('#my-form-id') returns an array of elements with that ID, which FormData probably doesn't understand, while $('#my-form-id')[0] (or $('#my-form-id').first()) returns a single form, which it does understand.